# Lambda functions SSM environment variables are not updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I created a new cognito stack. I can see in the parameter store that the variables are updated to have the new ids of the new Cognito stack.
However, in my lambdas the env variables are still pointing to the old cognito stack ids which is now deleted. It looks like a cache issue..
I tried deploy with `--no-previous-paremeters` but it didn't work, any idea on what should I do ?

```js
export class SSMParameterReader extends AwsCustomResource {
    constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
        const { parameterName, region } = props;

        const ssmAwsSdkCall: AwsSdkCall = {
            service: 'SSM',
            action: 'getParameter',
            parameters: {
                Name: parameterName,
            },
            region,
            physicalResourceId: { id: name }, // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
        };

        super(scope, name, {
            onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall,
            policy: {
                statements: [
                    new iam.PolicyStatement({
                        resources: ['*'],
                        actions: ['ssm:GetParameter'],
                        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                    }),
                ],
            },
        });
    }

    public getParameterValue(): string {
        return this.getResponseField('Parameter.Value').toString();
    }
}
```

And then I call this function to get my parameter

```js
export function getFromSSM(scope: Construct, paramName: string, env?: any): string {
    return new SSMParameterReader(scope, scope.node.id + paramName + 'Reader', {
        parameterName: paramName,
        region: env?.region || 'eu-central-1',
    }).getParameterValue();
}
```

Comment: No way to know without knowing how the environment variables are being populated. Add some code to the question.

Comment: @gshpychka I updated the answer with a code snippet

Comment: Why not use the CDK's own cloud-side lookup method, [StringParameter.valueFromLookup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#static-valuewbrfromwbrlookupscope-parametername)?  It will [fetch and cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods) the parameter value at synth-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to randomize the `physicalResourceId` so the custom resource will recieve the Update event and always invoke the SDK call, i.e.

```
physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString())
```

Consider the following code:

```js
export interface SSMParameterReaderProps {
  readonly parameterName: string;
  readonly region: string;
};

export class SSMParameterReader extends cr.AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
      const { parameterName, region } = props;

      const ssmAwsSdkCall: cr.AwsSdkCall = {
          service: 'SSM',
          action: 'getParameter',
          parameters: {
              Name: parameterName,
          },
          region,
          physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()), // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
      };

      super(scope, name, {
          onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall,
          policy: {
              statements: [
                  new iam.PolicyStatement({
                      resources: ['*'],
                      actions: ['ssm:GetParameter'],
                      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                  }),
              ],
          },
      });
  }

  public getParameterValue(): string {
      return this.getResponseField('Parameter.Value').toString();
  }
}
```

And `app.ts`

```js
const app = new cdk.App();

const env =  { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION };

const stack = new cdk.Stack(app, 'SSMCreator', { env })
new ssm.StringParameter(stack, 'Foo', { parameterName: 'foo', stringValue: 'bar' });

const reader = new SSMParameterReader(stack, 'SSMReader', {
  parameterName: 'foo',
  region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION || 'us-east-1',
});
new cdk.CfnOutput(stack, 'Value', { value: reader.getParameterValue()});
```

On initial deployment, you get `bar` as the initial value:

```
Outputs:
SSMCreator.Value = bar
```

Now, let's update it with AWS CLI:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name foo --value $(date +%s) --overwrite
```

deploy again and you get the new value:

```
Outputs:
SSMCreator.Value = 1680733424
```

Let me know if it works for you.